# How can I process C++ definitions in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, constants

I have a bunch of *.h files, containing only c-style definitions like

```
#define ALPHA_REACTOR_CODE 99641
#define BETA_REACTOR_CODE  99642
#define GAMMA_REACTOR_CODE 99643
#define DELTA_REACTOR_CODE 99644
```

How can I use this files in my С# code without changes and work with this constant in my code?

Comment: You'll need to process these declarations to generate C# equivalents.

Comment: You meen I need parser to generate constants list?

Comment: @kandreych: do you need this as design time? or just runtime?

Comment: @AlastairPitts it is common files for 2 different projects, so i don't want do duplicate them, because it may cause some sync errors in future

Comment: i meant, do you need the ability to use this constant during design time? Or would runtime be ok? Also, are they always integer values?

Comment: @AlastairPitts: yes, they used only in runtime. and yes, constants are always integers

Comment: @kandreych: I have an idea that you can try, but i'm about to head home from work, so I'll post an answer in the next hour or so.

Comment: @kandreych: Yes, you need a "parser".  Given your example, it seemed reasonable to assume that all your #defines were simply symbolic names for constants.   You can build a completely ad hoc string parser to process these pretty easily.  Other answers have suggested some ways to encode the collected constants, but how you encode them depends on your needs; you could simply write them as pairs of <name,value> in a file and read them in at runtime, if your program doesn't need to access them fast.  (Arguably you could read the C headers in your program and search for them, but that will be slow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*apologies for the late answer when I promised one earlier.*

The idea I have involves using the runtime code compiler as well as reflection to dynamically generate a class that contains all these constants.

So the steps (or pseudocode), as I see it are:

1. For each .h file read all the lines that begin with `#define` and store these.
2. Using `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider()` and an empty template file, compile a DLL in memory that contains a class that exposes `public const int ALPHA_REACTOR_CODE = 99641;` style  constants.
3. Use `Assembly.GetType(string)` to get the type of your generated class
4. Use Reflection and a method that takes the constant name to access the value.

So if that's our plan of attack, here is some snippets of code that may help you.

**1. Loading the .h files**
This is pretty basic file reading, the key trick is to filter your lines by `#define` and then parse to a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

```
lines.Where(line => line.StartsWith("#define", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                .Select(line => line.Split(' ').Skip(1))
                .ToDictionary(lineParts => lineParts.First(), lineParts => int.Parse(lineParts.Last()));
```

This will generate a dictionary of all your definitions. You may want to do a `.Distict()` call before the `.ToDictionary()` just in case there is duplicate definitions.

**2. Generating the Assembly**
This is where you use the `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider()` to generate a in-memory assembly. The trick here is to have a "GenerateCode.cs" file that contains a basic structure for a class. This must be set as a EmbeddedResource, otherwise it will try and be compiled (which won't work).

```
using System;

namespace GeneratedCode
{{
    public class GeneratedConstants
    {{

{0}

    }}
}}
```

You'll note the `{0}`, we use that with a `string.Format` to insert the constants into the file.

Use `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()` to get a stream of this template file and a normal `StreamReader` to read this into one big string in memory.

Generate the constants by using a `StringBuilder` and basic `string.Format()` formatting coupled with the Dictionary of values.

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var constant in dict)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "public const int {0} = {1};", constant.Key, constant.Value);
    }
```

Then just use string.Format() to insert the builder string into the generated class string (using the `{0}`)

Then, you just need to use the `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider()` to generate an assembly in memory.

```
 using (CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
            {
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");

                CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceCode);

            }
```

**3 & 4. Using Reflection**
now you have an assembly that contains a type with your constants defined in it, you can use `assembly.GetType("GeneratedCode.GeneratedConstants");` to get the type, and use Reflection to get the constants out, either one at a time or all together.

Have a look at this blog post which covers how to get a const using reflection: http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2003/02/20/2708.aspx

Well I hope that helps you out. It's not an overly complex solution, but has a few moving parts.

Good luck!

Comment: This solution seems to be so perfect. Btw, as you said GenerateCode.cs must be set as embedded resource. I suppose source *.h files should be embedded either, as far as otherwise they must be somewhere nearby exe all the time?

Comment: @kandreych: up to you, personally I would have them as embedded resources, that way you are guarantee they are there after compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Write a program to convert the C style .h file to the C# equivalent. If, as claimed, the .h file only contains int #defines, this should be pretty trivial in your language of choice.

Ideally, the conversion will be integrated properly into your build/make process so it will be redone when/if the .h file changes.

Comment: +1 pretty trivial to do thus in perl, python etc. And very effecitve

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if what you wants is possible. However, for what's worth it here is the C# way:

C# does not support #define the same way c++ does. I think you would have to write those constants as either enums or const values. e.g.

```
enum REACTOR
{
    ALPHA = 99641,
    BETA = 99642,
    GAMMA = 99643,
    DELTA = 99641
}
```

or use constants, as these values are replaced at compile time

```
const int ALPHA_REACTOR = 99641;
```

If you have a lot of those values (an .h classes) I suppose you could make a "constant" container class which holds all of them in separate enums describing the values inside (REACTOR, X, Y, Z) so you could simply call Constants.REACTOR.ALPHA in your code.

Favored this post as I am interested in the actual answer to this question. I'm wondering if it is possible what you want to do.

//edit
[This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/cc6ffcc7-1984-44b0-b79d-08770357eef0) suggests another option which I have quoted below.

> If you want, there's an alternate path you might want to explore:
>   Create an assembly that has all the constants in it, reference it from
>   your assembly and then compile. The constant values will be copied to
>   your code and since the constants' assembly will never be used, it
>   will never be looked for, allowing you to simply not distribute it.
>
> I would only recommend this after some very extensive testing, as I'm
>   not sure all JIT implementations will actually allow this.

It is not the same, but another option that generating additional C# code.

Comment: Well, I don't actually want to modify *.h files anyhow - they are  included from kinda read-only source.

Comment: @kandreych: Do not modify the the header files, create new C# files. You could generate them. The only other option is to NOT use C# and use (Managed) C++ instead.

Comment: @bastijn assembly requires recompilation each time *.h files will change, so it's not the best way I think

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want managed C++ to integrate your C code with C# code?